# Question about hardware impacts of caching

Tags: c#, caching

I'm just starting to try and reduce some DB round trips through caching information. I'm using this sort of thing...

```
        if (Cache["Testamonials"] != null)
        {
            allTestamonials = (Testamonials)Cache["Testamonials"];
        }
        else
        {
            allTestamonials = new Testamonials(_connection);
            Cache.Insert("Testamonials", allTestamonials, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }
```

And am obviously seeing dramatic increases in site performance as a result... I am having trouble tracking down information on the hardware impacts of doing this type of caching. For example, how much can I cache? How do I know if the cache is getting too big or is there any kind of tradeoff occurring here?

Apologies if this is a bit of a newbie question: Have been a developer for years but only just getting into the hardware side of things.

Answer (score 1):

This type of question is best awnsered by a profiler such as the one in VS ultimate, the [ANTS profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) or [one of these](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/profilers)

this type caching is called mem-caching and there are a number of libraries out there to doit. you can ofcourse roll your own, butyou have to deal with race conditions and things like that

You can also look at the caching that is build into IIS, since its very low level you can get some good perf boosts out of it

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of performance counters which you can monitor for caching. You can be safe in the knowledge that the cache used by asp.net is extremely smart and will use an appropriate amount of system resources and if the cache is causing the asp.net worker process unnecessary load the least frequently used items in the cache will start to expire. For details on the performance counters refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx).